# How do i convert string array into long array in Scala

Tags: scala

ex:

```
val ids = "1,2,3"
var result = ids.split(",")
```

I need to convert string array into long array in Scala

Answer (score 7):

```
val ids = "1,2,3"
val result = ids.split(",").map(_.toLong)

result: Array[Long] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val ids = "1 ,2,  3"
val result = ids.split(',').map(_.trim.toLong)
```

works also with spaces between the numbers, and performs marginally better because doesn't implicitly use a regexp for the splitting part.